# Trying to change fill color of svg when input is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have an SVG icon next to an input field. When the icon or input is hovered, both should change color together, and when either is clicked, the input should be focused and both should stay the hover color.

The problem I'm having is that the SVG won't keep the hover color when the input is focused. I've tried using `if ($('.input').is(':focus'))` but it takes me a step backwards in that it somehow prevents the color changing even on hover.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/co4an2t8/3/) - Uncomment the JS to check what I attempted in vain. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#current-amount-div').click(function() {
    $('.amount-input').focus();
  });

  /*if ($('.amount-input').is(":focus")) {
    $('.symbol-text').css({
      fill: '#3c93ae'
    });
  } else {
    $('.symbol-text').css({
      fill: '#6ab5cc'
    });
  }*/
});
```

```css
#current-amount-div {
  width: 163px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: color 0.25s, fill 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#current-amount-div:hover .amount-input {
  border-color: #3c93ae;
}

#current-amount-div:hover #oc-symbol text {
  fill: #3c93ae;
}

#oc-symbol {
  float: left;
}

#oc-symbol text {
  transition: fill 0.25s ease-out;
}

.symbol-text {
  fill: #6ab5cc;
}

.amount-input {
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  display: inline;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6ab5cc;
}

.amount-input:focus {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3c93ae;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-amount-div">
  <svg id="oc-symbol" width="36px" height="48px" viewBox="11.5 0 75 100" enable-background="new 11.5 0 75 100" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <text class="symbol-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 5.8066 87.1475)" font-family="'Apple-Chancery'" font-size="112.6105">C</text>
      <text class="symbol-text" transform="matrix(0.8797 0.0076 -0.0087 1 29.2212 72.208)" font-family="'AvenirNext-MediumItalic'" font-size="79.8022">o</text>
    </g>
  </svg>

  <input class="amount-input" type="number" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current `HTML` structure is as follows:

```
<div id="current-amount-div">
    <svg id="oc-symbol" width="36px" height="48px">
        <g>
            <text>C</text>
            <text>o</text>
        </g>
     </svg>
     <input class="amount-input" type="number" />
</div>
```

As `<svg>` comes before `<input>`, it can't be selected with pure css selectors. However if you switch the order of both elements in your `HTML` as shown below:

```
<div id="current-amount-div">
    <input class="amount-input" type="number" />
    <svg id="oc-symbol" width="36px" height="48px">
        <g>
            <text>C</text>
            <text>o</text>
        </g>
     </svg>
 </div>
```

As now `<svg>` is coming after `<input>`, we can select and style it with `+` sibling selector i.e `input:focus + svg` will select the `<svg>` when preceding input is focused.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#current-amount-div').click(function() {
    $('.amount-input').focus();
  });
});
```

```css
#current-amount-div {
  width: 163px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: color 0.25s, fill 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#current-amount-div:hover .amount-input {
  border-color: #3c93ae;
}

#current-amount-div:hover #oc-symbol text {
  fill: #3c93ae;
}

#oc-symbol {
  float: left;
}

#oc-symbol text {
  transition: fill 0.25s ease-out;
}

.symbol-text {
  fill: #6ab5cc;
}

.amount-input {
  float: right;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  display: inline;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6ab5cc;
}

.amount-input:focus {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3c93ae;
}

.amount-input:focus + #oc-symbol .symbol-text {
  fill: #3c93ae;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-amount-div">
  <input class="amount-input" type="number" />
  <svg id="oc-symbol" width="36px" height="48px" viewBox="11.5 0 75 100" enable-background="new 11.5 0 75 100" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <text class="symbol-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 5.8066 87.1475)" font-family="'Apple-Chancery'" font-size="112.6105">C</text>
      <text class="symbol-text" transform="matrix(0.8797 0.0076 -0.0087 1 29.2212 72.208)" font-family="'AvenirNext-MediumItalic'" font-size="79.8022">o</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh lovely, thanks so much! I was beating my head against the wall with JS when it turns out CSS had the solution all along. Yay.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Script**

Add One more Class `SvGFocusColor`. and this Class add only focus in textbox then apply  and remove focus then remove Class `SvGFocusColor'

```
$('.amount-input').focus(function () {
     $('.symbol-text').addClass('SvGFocusColor');
}).blur(function () 
{
  $('.symbol-text').removeClass('SvGFocusColor');

});
```

**Css**

```
.SvGFocusColor
    { 
    fill: #3c93ae !important;
    }
```

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/co4an2t8/6/)

**Snippet Example Below**

```js
    $('.amount-input').focus(function () {
         $('.symbol-text').addClass('SvGFocusColor');
    }).blur(function () 
    {
      $('.symbol-text').removeClass('SvGFocusColor');
      
    });
```

```css
#current-amount-div {
  width: 163px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: color 0.25s, fill 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#current-amount-div:hover .amount-input {
  border-color: #3c93ae;
}

#current-amount-div:hover #oc-symbol text {
  fill: #3c93ae;
}

#oc-symbol {
  float: left;
}

#oc-symbol text {
  transition: fill 0.25s ease-out;
}

.symbol-text {
  fill: #6ab5cc;
}

.amount-input {
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  display: inline;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6ab5cc;
}

.amount-input:focus {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3c93ae;
}
.SvGFocusColor
    { 
    fill: #3c93ae !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-amount-div" class="SvGFocusColor">
<svg id="oc-symbol" width="36px" height="48px" viewBox="11.5 0 75 100" enable-background="new 11.5 0 75 100" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <text class="symbol-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 5.8066 87.1475)" font-family="'Apple-Chancery'" font-size="112.6105">C</text>
    <text class="symbol-text" transform="matrix(0.8797 0.0076 -0.0087 1 29.2212 72.208)" font-family="'AvenirNext-MediumItalic'" font-size="79.8022">o</text>
  </g>
</svg>

<input class="amount-input" type="number" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sumit, I see that the icon does keep the darker color on focus. However, it doesn't meet my other requirement that the input is focused when the icon is clicked. Since Muhammad's answer addresses both parts and does so with just CSS, I'm accepting his answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need specific Javascript to implement this, you can use CSS for this, just like:

```css
.amount-input:focus ~ #oc-symbol .symbol-text {
  fill: #3c93ae;
}
```

Have look at the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#current-amount-div').click(function() {
    $('.amount-input').focus();
  });
});
```

```css
#current-amount-div {
  width: 163px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: color 0.25s, fill 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#current-amount-div:hover .amount-input {
  border-color: #3c93ae;
}

#current-amount-div:hover #oc-symbol text {
  fill: #3c93ae;
}

#oc-symbol {
  float: left;
}

#oc-symbol text {
  transition: fill 0.25s ease-out;
}

.symbol-text {
  fill: #6ab5cc;
}

.amount-input {
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  display: inline;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6ab5cc;
}

.amount-input:focus {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3c93ae;
}


.amount-input:focus ~ #oc-symbol .symbol-text {
  fill: #3c93ae;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-amount-div">
  <input class="amount-input" type="number" />
    <svg id="oc-symbol" width="36px" height="48px" viewBox="11.5 0 75 100" enable-background="new 11.5 0 75 100" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <text class="symbol-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 5.8066 87.1475)" font-family="'Apple-Chancery'" font-size="112.6105">C</text>
      <text class="symbol-text" transform="matrix(0.8797 0.0076 -0.0087 1 29.2212 72.208)" font-family="'AvenirNext-MediumItalic'" font-size="79.8022">o</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh interesting, I've never used ~ before. I see that you're using this in place of + from Sumit's answer, which required me to switch the order of `input` and `svg`. Does ~ find a sibling?

Comment: @dannyzaplings Yes! you need to switch the order of the elements as `~`. This is known as general sibling combinator - The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~) character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the second one.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your wisdom, @saurav!

Comment: @dannyzaplings My pleasure!